# Is it possible to send a "silent" push notification on iPhone (without any alert to the user)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I need to do it on a chat app to notice the client that there is new data to fetch from the server.

I know that technically it is possible with an empty payload (at least on ios 5 device it worked), but can Apple see it as abuse of service or is it OK to do it?

And is it technically possible on ios 4 device?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the user to know there is new data?

Comment: Because you need to download the data before show him nothing. I mean, you know you received a pic, but you want to download it before tell him that. Is a usabillity issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, increment only badge number, dont send sound and alert, So, there will be one badge on the App icon.

So, here unknowingly the badge number will be incremented to show that something has been recieved when user watches the app icon.

But your device won't recive alert or empty payload and won't recieve sound also because you asked for “silent” push notification on iPhone

and while configuring in AppDelegate, configure only badges

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge];
```

Hope this will be helpful for you

Comment: I need to be able sending push with sound and alert sometimes, so I don't want to configure it this way. From what I tested if I send push without payload (I can still send badge number) it works. But I didn't tested it on iOS 4, and I don't know if it ok by apple to do so.

Comment: Do you know if Apple see it as abuse of service or is it OK to do it?

Comment: it is OK, apple wont abuse it

Comment: Apple offer you that possibility and it's not marked as abuse of services. I used it for a long time and never had problems with the quantity of sended push notifications.

Answer (score 5):

You need to build the payload like this:

```
String payload = 
'{
    "aps":{
        "content-available": 1 
    }, 
    "data_id": 5, 
    "additional_data": ["some", "data"]
}'
```

In aps put the apple variales needed to make the push notification display a text, sound, badge... or just content-available to make it silent. Then, out of 'aps{...}' and separated with ',' put your custom fields to send the needed information for the download.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the badge number to increase you could also try sending a sound notification which plays a silent sound file. (Unfortunately, I don't know if this is ok for Apple).

Comment: This should be fine as well. Tho you're not really sending an audio file, but merely referencing an audio file already in the apps bundle. If that audio file is silent, that is perfectly fine. Though it might be noticeable if you receive a push when listening to music.